# advanced selection problem

Tags: jquery, class, selection, parent

Okay... 
how do I select a element's parent's child with specyfied class name..?

Answer (score 5):

an "element's parent's child" is called a [sibling](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/siblings):

```
$(this).siblings(".theClassYou'reAfter")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent("div").child(".className")
```

also, a parent element's child is technically a sibling of the current element, so you could try:

```
$(this).siblings(".className")
```

Comment: next specifically looks at the next sibling - your second example won't work if the element with class .classname doesn't follow the original element immediately.

Comment: parent only goes to the err parent so the filter is pretty useless unless you only want the parent if it is indeed a div. .closest() is a better choice if you want to search up until a match.